# Trying to put child div over a parent div

Tags: html, css

At the moment I'm trying to make a system where once something happens, there will be a big div and error message over the current div to say that the user can no longer interact with the parent div.

The way I tried doing this (in the child element to the parent) was adding a `position: absolute;` and `top: 0; left:0` but that just made everything weirdly aligned and kind of ruined the flow and build of the divs.

So my question is, is there a better way to display a div over another div where, for example, I could make it's opacity 0.8, and be able to see through it, over the entire div behind it, kind of like a `z-index: 1;`.

**JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/331nr1L0/**

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: whether absolute positioning will throws off your layout or not will depend largely on your layout itself... there are plenty of solutions out there on how to do this reliably and consistently...

Comment: this works but there may be a more elegant way, depending on the context.

https://jsfiddle.net/xLqabrdo/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just make the parent position relative then set absolute positioning on the child. I'd need to see more examples of how everything got weirdly aligned like you mentioned.

```css
.parent {
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: lightgrey;
   border: solid black 1px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: hsla(270, 100%, 50%, .4);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  
  <div class="child">
     
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated your jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/331nr1L0/1/

Comment: Dang, beat me to it by 5 seconds.

Comment: Yours was the one of the pile that worked, thanks for the help @zoite !:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the transparency as you mentioned if you would like, just remember that css changes made to the parent div will fall through to the child div, unless you overwrite them by specifying a different value for the same option in the child. EG

```
.parent {
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: lightgrey;
   border: solid black 1px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   opacity:0.5;
}

.child {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to overlap the child over the parent, I'd adjust the margins as well.

Change the colours you want and this should do the trick (as an alternative to the other responses)

Here, the child has a dashed white border (change it to solid, any colour you want)

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: solid black 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.child {
  border: 5px dashed white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.4;
  height: 210px;
  width: 110%;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  margin: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">

  </div>
</div>
```